# PFImageView inside custom UITableViewCell displaying incorrectly with contentMode "AspectFill"

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, parse-platform

I want to display data (a background image and a label) from PFObjects in a table view rows.

What I have:

- A `MainTableViewController` inheriting from `PFQueryTableViewController`
- A `MainTableViewCell` inheriting from `UITableViewCell`
- A `UILabel` and a `PFImageView` inside the content view of the `MainTableViewCell`
- Set a custom row height for the cell in the storyboard, and in the view controller via `heightForRowAtIndexPath` (not sure if I need both?)

If I set the contentMode of the background image to "Aspect Fit" or "Scale To Fill", the background images show up correctly in the cells.

But if I set it to "Aspect Fill" (which is the one I actually want), the background image of one cell "bleeds" into the other cells next to it, basically ignoring the frame and the row height, growing in height until the image is fully shown in the correct aspect ratio, and not clipped as usual.

It does not matter if I inherit from `UITableViewCell` or `PFTableViewCell` - the behaviour is the same.

It also does not matter if I set the contentMode in code or in the storyboard.

How can I display the background image correctly with "Aspect fill"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like all you need is to set `imageView.clipsToBounds = YES`

Also, you only need `heightForRowAtIndexPath` if the heights of your cells vary from cell to cell. Otherwise, setting it in the storyboard is fine.